# Multiplexed CAN Bus

Tags: embedded, can, multiplexer

I have a need to mux the CANH/CANL lines from a single MCU controller/transceiver to multiple pins on an existing connector series.  The flow I am looking at would be something like:

MCU <--> Xcvr <--> AMux (or other?) <--> Protection Circuitry <--> Connector/Bus

The AMux is not going to be able to handle the same bus conditions (short to VBAT, load dump, etc.) that the CAN transceiver would allow for so I'm also going to need a way to protect the AMux.

Note that the interconnect is set up at initialization and does not have to adjust on the fly.  The mux is necessary because there are various pinouts that we have to interface in to.

Any guidance/thoughts appreciated.

UPDATE: Appreciate the thought on relay and it's a good solution, but I am very size limited.  What I need is something on the order of a 2-to-12 mux (preferably serially controlled).  It seems doing this with relays would blow away my form factor.

Comment: A thought: reed relay.

Comment: Look at ONSemi AMIS-42770, can gang them together to get more CANbus ports.